# @Inject into Jax-rs resource: CWWAM0002E: An exception occurred while merging an annotation into deployment descriptor:

Tags: path, jax-rs, cdi, websphere-8, inject

I am getting a weird exception when I deploy Rest sevice locally to my WAS 85 environment in eclipse:

```
CWWAM0002E: An exception occurred while merging an annotation into deployment descriptor: com.ibm.wsspi.amm.merge.MergeException: Unable to find EnterpriseBean for class WackyDoodleResource
                             com.ibm.wsspi.amm.merge.MergeException: Unable to find EnterpriseBean for class WackyDoodleResource
```

This is not my real code but here is how I set it up with names changed to protect the innocent:

```
@Path("/wacky-doodle-resource")
public class WackyDoodleResource{
       @Context UriInfo uriInfo
       @Context SecurityContext securityContext;
       @Inject WackyDoodleEJB wackyDoodleEJB;

       @POST
       @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATIONI_JSON)
       @RolesAllowed("WACKYDOODLES")
       @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATIONI_JSON)
       public Response createWackyDoodle(WackyDoodleRequestRO requestRO{
              String response = null;
              response = wackyDoodleEJB.createWackyDoodle(requestRO)
       }
       return Response.ok(response)).build();

}



@Default
@Singleton
public class WackyDoodleEJB implements IWackyDoodleEJB{

public String createWackyDoodle(WackyDoodleRequestRO req){
       System.out.println("Do Something Wacky!");
       }
}

public interface IWackyDoodleEJB{
       public String createWackyDoodle(WackyDoodleRequestRO request);
}
```

(Simple recreation of my more complex code for illustration purposes)

I see that exception when I deploy my ear to my local Websphere server.  The application appears to start up and deploy just fine (if you don't pay attention to what you find in the logs).  However, when I attempt to hit any of my http request @myResources, I get this oddly nondescript message

```
E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer handleRequest SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle / has not been defined.
```

I suspect it has something to do with my ear not publishing correctly (the exception in my question). I honestly do not know however.  So, what could be happening here?  This seems like it should be pretty boilertplate stuff?
The error suggests that I should Turn my regular resource pojo into an EJB?  If I add, for example, the stateless @nnotation to my class, the above exception in the logs goes away, but I am still not able to hit my sevice resources.  I get the same nondescript exception.  I am at a loss and I have been looking at this for an hour.  If you could point me in any direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Try using these directions at IBM devWorks to troubleshoot the webcontainer error first, https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/How_to_diagnose_error_SRVE0255E?lang=en.  You may be right, the AMM exception may be ignorable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Yeah, I looked at that link and it seems like everything is ok.  That is what made me suspect that something was going on with my ear.

Comment: Hello,
I have encountered this problem too.
I discovered that this Exception is thrown only if @RolesAllowed is defined in the RestService Resource class
Did you manage to fix this problem?